# Error Nmap: 'dnet: Failed to open device wifi0' on Ubuntu (W10 bash)

Tags: linux, networking, windows-10, bash, nmap

I have an issue when using nmap.

When i want to execute any command, nmap anwsers me :

Nmap: 'dnet: Failed to open device wifi0'

I am working on Ubuntu with the W10 bash subsystem.

I red here https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/1349 that some packets aren't supported on the W10 bash, do you think that's the answer ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, generally speaking Nmap is not supported on Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL). The WSL folks don't like statements like this, though, because support is always improving. You can track [this particular issue (Nmap support in WSL) on Github](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/1349).

Answer (score 1):

Try --unprivileged option. It worked for me